# Angular $scope variable breaking on update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Menu controller I have a function to save a Menu. The $scope.menu variable holds the object that represents my menu data. The saveMenu function sends an Ajax call off to a REST API endpoint and then receives the updated menu back as a response.  The problem is that when I assign $scope.menu to the response all my data bindings in the HTML template break.  Suddenly all the menu data disappears.

The controller code.

```
$scope.saveMenu = function() {
  var menu = $scope.createJsonMenuRequest();
  var method = "PUT";
  var url =  FoodUrls.foodAPI + "menus/" + menu.id;

  var req = {
    method: method,
    url: url,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: angular.toJson(menu)
  };

  $http(req).success(function(data) {
    $scope.menu = $.extend(true, {}, data);
  });    
};
```

The createJsonMenuRequest function simply goes through the menu and removes some properties from the copy that the API doesn't like.

Why does the binding to the HTML template break?

**Updated**

Before the assignment statement in the success function, the $scope.menu looks something like this.

```
{
   name: "My Menu",
   sections: [
      { $$hashKey: "object:17", id: 1, name: "blarg"}
   ]
}
```

Afterwards it looks like this...

```
{
   name: "My Menu",
   sections: [
      { id: 1, name: "blarg-edited"}
   ]
}
```

It loses the $$hashKeys that Angular is putting in there when the menu is originally created.  Not sure what the significance of that is.

Comment: If all of your binding break then surely you have an error in the console. Have you checked to see what it is?

Comment: You have verified that you get the desired value from your ajax requset?
Have you tried using angulars extend function?  [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

Comment: @MatthewGreen There are no errors.  My suspicion about what is happening is that when all the bindings that are to things like menu.sections is broken when that menu.sections is replaced with a new object.  The object that ng-repeat was initially referencing is no longer there.  What I don't know how to do is to make Angular go back through and rebuild the references using the new object.

Comment: @Erex Yes, I'm getting the correct data back.  I haven't tried the Angular merge or extend functions.  I will do so and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Have you try using rootScope instead of scope ?? propably u try acess to not accessibility part of scope. Try and give a feedback ;)

Comment: The big difference between the $scope.menu before and after the $.extend statement is that before the items in the arrays have $$hashKey properties while the newly assigned $scope.menu does not.  I'll update the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using jQuery's extend functions against any property on an angular $scope. $scope is a complicated object with lots of pointers to specific properties and such. I would recommend using angular.merge, as it should do a better job of merging the objects correctly without breaking the scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge

Comment: lol man, just look into hes code :D he already doing $scope.menu = $.extend(true,{},data);

Comment: Daredzik, thanks for pointing out my typo. I forgot to edit it after copy/paste. This is what I meant:       After taking another look, you're doing a deep merge with an empty object as the target. Why not just do: `code` $scope.menu = data;

Comment: @abiwer This seems to have done the trick.  Not sure what jQuery's extend was screwing up but Angular's merge doesn't seem to be breaking things at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I'll just put this here.

How far did you debug?

I'd look at $scope.menu before the update, and then again after in your success method.

What's your data / template look like?

And just for my own curiosity, why the deep $.extend ? Could be totally valid, I've just never used it in this way.

Saw your update, the $hashkey shouldn't be an issue, if you don't want it, you angular.copy(data) or simply put a track by in your ng-repeat :

```
data-ng-repeat="item in menuItems track by $index"
```

Comment: I used the extend because it makes a deep copy of the object and returns it.